# Get only numeric value keyword from edittext in android

Tags: android, keyword, numeric

I want to open a only numeric keyword for input in edittext in android.

Comment: what was that? posting a too basic question and then posting its answer

Comment: Please do search feature before posting a question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

Comment: you know the answer then why you have asked question?